# Will ROS 2 Dashing support RTI Connext 6.0.0?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install RTI Connext from the RTI website, the version available for download is the new 6.0.0. But I am unable to build ROS 2 master with that version.

The new version seems to have multiple fixes including in the security plugins (part that I'm interested in).

Will ROS 2 Dashing target Connext 6.0.0, or will it target version Connext 5.3.1 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320064/will-ros-2-dashing-support-rti-connext-6.0.0-?/) by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3606 on 2019-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-01**:
We are still waiting for RTI to provide us with an updated Debian package. Once that is available we will be looking into supporting it.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2019-04-01**:
Sounds good thanks!
Should I close this or keep it opened and you'll post an answer once the definitive answer is known?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-01**:
Keeping it open until the answer is `yes` or `no` sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 Dashing has been [officially released](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-2-dashing-diademata-released/9365) and is targeting [RTI Connext 5.3.1](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/3ac2eedc61a266b340627fa5b4cbc7af93dce294/rep-2000.rst#dashing-diademata-may-2019---may-2021)

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0